# Updating DataGrid in WPF with Caliburn Micro

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid, caliburn.micro

I am working on a WPF project using Caliburn Micro. In this app I have a `DataGrid`, which I populate with data from a SQL Server database using Dapper. Please consider the following code snippets:

**ChangesModel.cs**

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace PTSRDesktopUI.Models
{
    //public class for all changes attributes
    public class ChangesModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Facility { get; set; }
        public string Controller { get; set; }
        public string ParameterName { get; set; }
        public string OldValue { get; set; }
        public string NewValue { get; set; }
        public DateTime ChangeDate { get; set; }

        private bool _validated;
        public bool Validated
        {
            get { return _validated; }
            set { _validated= value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
        }

        public DateTime? ValidationDate { get; set; }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

**OverviewViewmodel.cs**

```
using Caliburn.Micro;
using PTSRDesktopUI.Helpers;
using PTSRDesktopUI.Models;

namespace PTSRDesktopUI.ViewModels
{
    public class OverviewViewModel : Screen
    {

        //Create new Bindable Collection variable of type ChangesModel
        public BindableCollection<ChangesModel> Changes { get; set; }


        public OverviewViewModel()
        {
            //Create connection to dataAccess class
            DataAccess db = new DataAccess();

            //get the changes from dataAccess function and store them as a bindabla collection in Changes
            Changes = new BindableCollection<ChangesModel>(db.GetChangesOverview());

            //Notify for changes
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Changes);

        }

        //Validate_Btn click event
        public void Validate()
        {

            //TODO: Change CheckBox boolean value to true and update DataGrid
        }
    }
}
```

**OverviewView.xaml**

```
    <!--Datagrid Table-->
    <DataGrid Grid.Row="1" x:Name="Changes" CanUserAddRows="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
        <!--..........-->
        <!--Some irrelevant code-->
        <!--..........-->
            <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <CheckBox x:Name="Validated_CheckBox" IsChecked="{Binding Path=Validated, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" IsHitTestVisible ="False"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Path=ValidationDate, TargetNullValue='NaN',
                                StringFormat='{}{0:dd.MM HH:mm}'}"/>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn CellStyle="{StaticResource DataGridCellCentered}">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button x:Name="Validate_Btn" cal:Message.Attach="[Event Click] = [Action Validate]"
                            Visibility="{Binding DataContext.Validated, 
                               Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridCell}}"
                            cal:Bind.Model="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}">Validate</Button>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

What I would like to accomplish is this:
When the user clicks the Validate `Button`, the boolean value for the `CheckBox` is set to true, the `ValidationDate` is set to now and the `DataGrid` is updated. I will then fire a stored procedure to update the database table as well. Also note that the `Button` is only visible if the `CheckBox` is checked. So all I want to know is how would I access the `Validated` property and `ValidationDate` in the `ViewModel` method `Validate()`. Also, how would I update the `DataGrid` after I change the values for `Validated` and `ValidationDate`, so that if I open another `ContentControl`, the values don't reset? 
Anyone have any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the signature of your `Validate` method in the view model to accept a `ChangesModel`:

```
public void Validate(ChangesModel model)
{
    model.ChangeDate = DateTime.Now;
}
```

...and change your XAML markup to this:

```
<Button x:Name="Validate_Btn"
        cal:Message.Attach="[Event Click] = [Action Validate($this)]"
        cal:Action.TargetWithoutContext="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}"
        Visibility="...">Validate</Button>
```

For the data in the `DataGrid` to get refreshed, you also need to raise the `PropertyChanged` event for the `ChangeDate` property:

```
private DateTime _changeDate;
public DateTime ChangeDate
{
    get { return _changeDate; }
    set { _changeDate = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
}
```

Comment: Hi again. Thanks for your reply. I  tried your suggestion but I get a `System.NullReferenceException` error because `model` in the signature of the `Validate` method is null when I click the button.

Comment: @Rei: Did you set the `cal:Action.TargetWithoutContext` attached property in the XAML as per my answer?

Comment: I did but i forgot to take out `cal:Bind.Model`. It works now. Thanks!